# How to make span to move to line 2 if there isn't enough text in line 1?

Tags: javascript, html

Have a look at this jsbin https://jsbin.com/dipater/edit?html,css,output
I want the span to appear on line 2 in both cases (container 1 and 2). How can this be achieved?

```
x
```

Comment: .no-style {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    cursor: auto;
    display: block;
}

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: what is that `x`? instead of giving jsbin/fiddle reference, you can create snippet in your question. If you don't know, at-least place your code in the question.

Comment: you can add a </br> tag before span.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do - but if its to get the text in the span AFTER the link to be on a second line - then simply apply a display: block style rule to the span in the a. You can style it to not be like a link if you want - but really if the span is not a part of the link - then it should be moved out of the `<a>` element.

```css
a span {display:block}
```

```html
  <div class="container-1 container">
    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/">this is some text <span class="no-style">more text</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="container-2 container">
    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/">this is some text <span class="no-style">more text</span></a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set span to display:block

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this
one is

```
.no-style {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    cursor: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image]